# React useEffect missing dependency for a function?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
useEffect(() => {
    calculateTip();
  }, [bill, tipPercentage, numberOfPeople]);

  const calculateTip = () => {
    const tip = ((tipPercentage / 100) * bill).toFixed(2);
    const tipPerGroup = ((tipPercentage / 100) * bill * numberOfPeople).toFixed(
      2
    );
    setTipPerGroup(tipPerGroup);

    setTip(tip);
  };
```

I get an error:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'calculateTip'. Either include it or remove the dependency array
```

Why does `useEffect` need to have a function in its dependency array? I mean the function never changes, it is the same same function, why does React force me to write it inside the dependency array?

Comment: Because it doesn't match the heuristics used to decide whether or not this is something that changes. In fact, if that function definition is inside the component, it _does_ change - you create a new function (albeit with the same logic inside) on every render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does useEffect need to have a function in its dependency array. I
> mean the function never changes . It is the same same function why
> does react force me to write it inside the dependency array?

If that function is defined inside the component then it is not the same function, on the contrary it is re-created on each render. But that is not much related to the reason for the warning.

The reason why that warning asks  you to put the function as dependency is the same as for other variables. *The function itself may be referencing some variables which may become stale*.

Comment: Hey @GiorgiMoniava i have run into another error `The 'calculateTip' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 28) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'calculateTip' in its own useCallback()` Any ideas?

Comment: @AmosMachora that message gives you two options for solving the problem - did you try either of them?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I honestly didn't understand anything that error said. I'm kind of a noob in react .

Comment: @AmosMachora Here is more reading: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies

Comment: @AmosMachora one of those suggestions isn't specific to React. For the other did you consider reading about the useCallback hook?

Comment: For example it says I move it into the callback. But it already is in a callback. What does it mean exactly.

Comment: @AmosMachora in your example it's _not_ already inside a callback. `calculateTip` is defined _outside_ the `useEffect` callback.

Comment: I got it know. It means the declaration not the reference thanks @GiorgiMoniava